# Is the narrator "Maslama bin Abdullah bin Urwa" the same person who is "Maslama bin Abdullah Juhani"?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, islamic-basis, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

Maslamah bin Abdullah bin Urwa is a narrator who is found in Tabaqat al-Kubra 2/271 here:-

al-maktaba.org/book/9351/2582#p1

A similar narrator with a slightly different name is also mentioned in Sunan Abu Dawud. His name is Maslama bin Abdullah Juhani. He can be found here:-

https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/86

But the main question is: are these both narrators (Maslama bin Adullah bin Urwa and Maslama bin Abdullah Juhani) the same person/narrator?

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same apparently.

The longer name of Maslamah ibn Abdullah Al-Juhani is mentioned in Tahzeeb Al-Tahzeeb [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/3310/4734#p1). Namely, his grandfather's name is Raba'ee, not Urwa.

His full name would be Maslamah ibn Abdullah ibn Raba'ee Al-Juhani.

Comment: What is the status of the narrator Maslamah bin abdullah bin Urwa? Is he Thiqa (Trustworthy)?

Comment: @Ren That would be a different question. And I have no idea.

Comment: @Ren Maslamah ibn 'Abdullah ibn 'Urwa doesn't seem to appear in Tahdheeb a-Tahdheeb which doesn't really surprise me as only a few Scholars (found only a single one  "ibn Hebban" so far) seem to identify him as a "known" narrator and person.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - I think he is trustworthy. He has narrated many narrations. One is also found in Mustadrik Al-Sahihain. He is acceptable according to [THIS SOURCE](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/31626/%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7...)

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Abu Hatim bin Hibban Al-Busti: He mentioned it in trustworthiness and said: It is narrated on the authority of his father and Abu Hazim, narrated by Abdul Aziz bin Muhammad Al-Darawardi

Comment: @Ren ibn Hebban is among the most lenient scholars in jarh wa-ta'adil.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - I do not think any scholar has objected against Ibn Hibban's verdict when it comes to accepting narrators.